# Enhanced for loop not getting executed when trying to call a method which throws an exception

Tags: java, arraylist, exception

I have 2 classes 1.employee management class which has an arraylist of employee type & 2. Employee class. I have to add employee to an arraylist after checking for alreadyexists exception.
The code i have in employment management class is.

```
    ArrayList<Employee> eme = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    boolean addEmployee(Employee emp){

    for(Employee e:eme)
    {
    if (e.getEmpId()==emp.getEmpId())
      {
        throw new AlreadyExistsException();
      }
    else if  (e.getEmpId()!=emp.getEmpId())
      {
       eme.add(emp);
      }
    return true;
    }
```

In my employee class i have constructors,getters and setters.In main method i created an employee management class object em, and called addEmployee method

```
    em.addEmployee(e1);
```

The problem is since the arraylist in employee management class is null, the for loop is not getting executed, and i am not able to check the employee already exists exception. How to resolve this? (Its my practice assignment)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please could you format your code more readably, and post *real* code rather than pseudo-code? (The "Public" here shows this isn't your real code.) It doesn't need to be your actual business code, but a sample that demonstrates the same problem. If you could expand it to a [mcve] that would be even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just a simple if condition as follows :

```
public void addEmployee(Employee emp) throws Exception {
    if (eme.size() == 0) {                          // add as list is empty
        eme.add(emp);
    } else {
        for (Employee e : eme) {                    // your logic as it is
            if (e.getEmpId() == emp.getEmpId()) {
                throw new Exception();
            } else if (e.getEmpId() != emp.getEmpId()) {
                eme.add(emp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can tweak the logic of making *this* method return a `boolean` as required. That is left for you as an exercise!

Answer (score 0):

You intended the following.

```
public boolean addEmployee(Employee emp) {
    for (Employee e: eme) {
        if (e.getEmpId() == emp.getEmpId()) {
           throw new AlreadyExistsException();
        }
    }
    eme.add(emp);
    return true;
}
```

A boolean result is not needed here.

Adding to `eme` should be done *outside* the loop on `eme` - otherwise a ConcurrentModificationException is thrown.

---

***Tip***

Also one could write:

```
List<Employee> eme = new ArrayList<>();
```

Or use a Set:

```
Set<Employee> eme = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingLong(Employee::getEmpId));

if (!eme.add(emp)) {
    throw new AlreadyExistsException();
}
```

Comment: When i call the addEmployee method to add an employee, it doesn't go inside the loop. The eme list contains nothing.

Comment: @Gingermirus that is why my code adds the employee _after_ the loop that just ensures it is not already added.